# mysqlijs - Unable to insert value into table correctly ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW

Tags: sql, node.js

I need to implement mysq in a nodejs script that will be called using a cron. I've this code at the moment, and I will populate the table after some email sending operations are completed.

```js
    if( invoicesDetail.length > 0 ){
        invoicesDetail.forEach( (invoice) => {
            let data = {...}
            conn.query('INSERT INTO sent_invoices SET ? (email_op,email_pec,cedi,cpco,document_name,document_type,invoice_destination,pdv,sent_date,invoice_sended)', data, (error, results, fields) => {
                if( error ){
                  console.log(error);
                }
                console.log(results, fields);
            });
        });
    }
```

I'm not sure how to corerctly do the insert query, I have 11 columns but one is for the primary key. Into the documentation I've readed that I need also to [escape the values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) using the `conn.escape()` method. I've done a test but if I omit the id column of the database I will get an error about columns number.
`Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

How I can correctly insert the data and avoid the error?